# In alfresco repository how to create link for one folder to another folder using java api

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, opencmis, apache-chemistry

Hi guys i am beginner in alfresco.I have done many services such as creating folder,subfolder,uploading document,downloading document,creating permissions using cmis.
But i am not able to create link of one folder to another folder using cmis.
Somebody told me its not possible using cmis.
**Somehow i got this link** http://basanagowdapatil.blogspot.in/2011/01/code-for-creating-links-in-alfresco.html.
But this code is not in cmis.
I have never done this kind of programming.
Can somebody suggest me how to do this program in maven.
What dependency or jars i should add.
It is better if someone explain me step by step(in sense how to give authentication).
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got my answer and we can do the same using CMIS API.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.api.Folder;
import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.api.Session;
import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.PropertyIds;
import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.enums.BaseTypeId;
import org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import com.bizruntime.alfresco.session.CreateSession;
import com.bizruntime.alfresco.util.Config;

public class CreateLink {
    static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(CreateLink.class);

    public static void getLink() {
        // creating Session
        Session cmiSession = new CreateSession().getSession();
        log.debug("Session Created...");
        Map<String,Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put(PropertyIds.BASE_TYPE_ID, BaseTypeId.CMIS_ITEM.value());

        // Define a name and description for the link
        properties.put(PropertyIds.NAME, Config.getConfig().getProperty("nameOfLink"));
        properties.put("cmis:description", Config.getConfig().getProperty("linkDescription"));
        properties.put(PropertyIds.OBJECT_TYPE_ID, "I:app:filelink");

        // Define the destination node reference
        properties.put("cm:destination", Config.getConfig().getProperty("destination-nodRef"));

        // Choose the folder where the link to be create
        Folder rootFoler = cmiSession.getRootFolder();
        Folder targerFolder = (Folder) cmiSession.getObjectByPath(rootFoler.getPath() + Config.getConfig().getProperty("targetFolder"));
        cmiSession.createItem(properties, targerFolder);
        log.info("Link Created Successfully....");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BasicConfigurator.configure();
        CreateLink cl = new CreateLink();
        cl.getLink();               
    }
}
```

Code for creating folder link:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.api.Folder;
import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.api.Session;
import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.PropertyIds;
import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.enums.BaseTypeId;
import org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import com.bizruntime.alfresco.session.CreateSession;
import com.bizruntime.alfresco.util.Config;

public class CreateLink {
    static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(CreateLink.class);
    public static void getLink() {
        // creating Session
        Session cmiSession = new CreateSession().getSession();
        log.debug("Session Created...");
        Map<String,Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put(PropertyIds.BASE_TYPE_ID, BaseTypeId.CMIS_ITEM.value());

        // Define a name and description for the link
        properties.put(PropertyIds.NAME, Config.getConfig().getProperty("nameOfLink"));
        properties.put("cmis:description", Config.getConfig().getProperty("linkDescription"));
        properties.put(PropertyIds.OBJECT_TYPE_ID, "I:app:filelink");

        // Define the destination node reference
        properties.put("cm:destination", Config.getConfig().getProperty("destination-nodRef"));

        // Choose the folder where the link to be create
        Folder rootFoler = cmiSession.getRootFolder();
        Folder targerFolder = (Folder) cmiSession.getObjectByPath(rootFoler.getPath() + Config.getConfig().getProperty("targetFolder"));
        cmiSession.createItem(properties, targerFolder);
        log.info("Link Created Successfully....");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BasicConfigurator.configure();
        CreateLink cl = new CreateLink();
        cl.getLink();
    }
}
```